# Textbox only counts for one variable instead of summing both up

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a program that calculates the user's electricity bill. However, there's an issue, I only manage to calculate them one by one, but when I try to sum them up, it didn't work, it only displays the total of one variable instead of summing both up.

[image]

Here's the code, it's not the full code as it is very long since i need to calculate March to December, so i only took march and april.

(This is to determine price based on usage)

*The service tax is 6%*, I've already put it in the service tax variable.

```
    Select Case True
        Case mar >= 1 To mar <= 200
            unitsConsumedMar = mar
            marTotalAmount = (unitsConsumedMar * 0.109)
            serviceTax = marTotalAmount * serviceTax
            marTotalAmount += serviceTax
            TextBox16.Text = marTotalAmount.ToString("C2")


        Case apr >= 1 To apr <= 200
            unitsConsumedApr = apr
            aprTotalAmount = (unitsConsumedApr * 0.109)
            serviceTax = aprTotalAmount * serviceTax
            aprTotalAmount += serviceTax
            TextBox16.Text = aprTotalAmount.ToString("C2")
        End Select

    Select Case True

        Case mar > "200" And mar <= "300"
            unitsConsumedMar = mar
            marTotalAmount = (unitsConsumedMar * 0.153)
            serviceTax = marTotalAmount * serviceTax
            marTotalAmount += serviceTax
            TextBox16.Text = marTotalAmount.ToString("C2")


        Case apr > "200" And apr <= "300"
            unitsConsumedApr = apr
            aprTotalAmount = (unitsConsumedApr * 0.153)
            serviceTax = aprTotalAmount * serviceTax
            aprTotalAmount += serviceTax
            TextBox16.Text = aprTotalAmount.ToString("C2")
        End Select

      totalBill = Val(marTotalAmount) + Val(aprTotalAmount)
      textbox20.Text = totalBill.ToString("C2")
```

These all work if March is 200 and April is 201, but then textbox16 returns some weird amount, it looks like it sums up both the amount from march and april instead of adding it up to textbox20.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3siwu.png)

for some reason, if i put 200 in one textbox and 201 in another, it calculates correctly since 70.98 + 23.11 is 94.09, but the monthly total amount shouldn't be 70.98, since 23.11 + 32.60 is not even anywhere near 70...

Comment: You need to debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint at the top and then step through the code line by line, examining the state at each step. You know what you expect to happen before each step and you can compare that to what actually happens afterwards. As soon as the two don't match, you've found your issue and you can investigate that specifically, rather than settling for *"for some reason"*. Even if you still can't solve the issue, at least you can provide us with all the relevant information.

Comment: Do you mean for the first 200 units to be billed at $0.109 and anything over 200 units to be billed at $0.153? Or is the entire usage billed at the higher rate when it exceeds 200 units?

Comment: correct. but 1 unit = 0.109, and if it exceeds 200, then 1 unit = 0.153

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create custom function to calculate monthly amount:

```
Function GetMonthlyAmount(energyUsage As Double) As Double
    Dim discount As Double = 0.0
    Dim serviceTax As Double = 0.06
    Dim total As Double = 0.0
    
    Select Case energyUsage
        Case 1.0 To 200.00
            discount = 0.109
        Case 200.01 To 300.0
            discount = 0.153
        Case > 300.00
            discount = 0.169
        Case Else
            discount = 0.0100
    End Select
    
    total = energyUsage * discount
    total += (total * serviceTax)
    
    Return total
End Function
```

But above function returns only monthly amount. As far as i see, you want to get (and display) other values, like: discount, service tax, etc. So, i'd suggest to create custom class:

```
Public Class BillOfEnergyUsage
    Private st As Double = 0.06
    Private eu As Double = 0.0
    Private di AS Double = 0.0
    Private dia AS Double = 0.0
    Private ta As Double = 0.0
    
    Public Sub New(energyUsage As Double)
        eu = energyUsage
        di = Discount
        dia = DiscountAmount
        ta = TotalAmount
    End Sub
    
    Public ReadOnly Property ServiceTax As Double
        Get 
            Return st
        End Get
    End Property
    
    Public Property EnergyUsage As Double
        Get 
            Return eu
        End Get
        Set (value As Double)
            eu = value
        End Set
    End Property
    
    Public ReadOnly Property Discount As Double
        Get 
            Select Case eu
                Case 1.0 To 200.00
                    di = 0.109
                Case 200.01 To 300.0
                    di = 0.153
                Case > 300.00
                    di = 0.169
                Case Else
                    di = 0.0
            End Select
            Return di
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property DiscountAmount As Double
        Get 
            dia = eu * di
            Return dia
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property TotalAmount As Double
        Get 
            ta = dia
            ta += (ta * st)
            Return ta
        End Get
    End Property
    
    Public Overrides Function ToString() AS String
        Return $"Usage: {eu.ToString("C2")}, Service Tax: {st.ToString("P2")}, Discount: {di.ToString("P2")} - {dia.ToString("C2")}, Total: {ta.ToString("C2")}"
    End Function
    
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Sub Main
    Dim usages As Double() = {120.00, 200.00, 252.00, 300.00, 305.00} 'you have to init your data from textboxes
    Dim beulist As List(Of BillOfEnergyUsage) = New List(Of BillOfEnergyUsage)
    
    For Each usage As Double In usages
        Dim beu As BillOfEnergyUsage = New BillOfEnergyUsage(usage)
        beulist.Add(beu)
        Console.WriteLine(beu.ToString())
    Next
    
    Dim totalAmount = beulist.Sum(Function(x) x.TotalAmount)
    Console.WriteLine($"Total amount: {totalAmount.ToString("C2")}")
End Sub
```

Result:

```
Usage: RM120.00, Service Tax: 6.00%, Discount: 10.90% - RM13.08, Total: RM13.86
Usage: RM200.00, Service Tax: 6.00%, Discount: 10.90% - RM21.80, Total: RM23.11
Usage: RM252.00, Service Tax: 6.00%, Discount: 15.30% - RM38.56, Total: RM40.87
Usage: RM300.00, Service Tax: 6.00%, Discount: 15.30% - RM45.90, Total: RM48.65
Usage: RM305.00, Service Tax: 6.00%, Discount: 16.90% - RM51.55, Total: RM54.64
Total amount: RM181.13
```

Note, that you're able to get any bill from the list and access to its properties like this:

```
Dim bb As BillOfEnergyUsage = beulist(0) 'get first bill from list
Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", bb.EnergyUsage, bb.ServiceTax, bb.Discount, bb.TotalAmount)
```

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is I am counting monthly and through the use of a button. I only have one textbox to hold a value of the current variable, which is monthly total. Say that March is textbox5, and April is textbox6, if I put a number into textbox5, it will calculate everything into monthly total, but when I enter a number into April, the number will stack, and if I make either one of them to ReadOnly = true, then how will I be able to sum them up...

Comment: Sorry, i don't get you... The number of textboxes placed on the form and their "enabled" status is not important!  I assume that you don't know how to loop through the collection of textboxes. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I created a class for the data associated with the energy field. The shared fields hold values used across all instances of the class. These values are set in the `Form.Load` method by calling the `SetRates` method. Since this is a Shared method you do not have to create an instance of the class. The `MonthNumber` is used to order a list of energy bills. You may need to change the `CalculateGrossMonthlyBill` method because I assumed a graduated rate. The `ToString` method is used by the combo box to determine the display.

In the form design, I named each of the text boxes in the MonthlyEnergyUse group box by the month they represent. You probably want to start with a `.Text` property of 0. The `.Tag` property of each month is the number that represents the month. March is 3, April is 4 etc. These number will be used to order the list.

In the `Form.Load` the `Shared` rates are set. Altough I hard coded the values, they could be retrieved from a text file or database. If they need to be changed you would not have to recompile the program.

After the month text boxes are filled in, Button1 is clicked. First the user input is validated with a `.TryParse` function. We create a list of `EnergyBill`, then loop through each text box calling the constructor of the of `EnergyBill` passing in values from the text box properties. The constructor sets the `Read Only` properties of the class. This new `EnergyBill` is then added to the list.

Next the list is ordered by the `MonthNumber` with a bit of Linq magic. It is then bound to a ComboBox (this replaces the text box you have labeled Month on the right side of your form.

The grand total is calculated by using `.Sum` method of the list and displayed in a text box.

You can see the data of each month by selecting the month is the combo box. Items of a ComboBox are objects but the underlying type is `EnergyBill` so we can cast the item and access all the properties.

```
Public Class EnergyBill
    Private _MonthlyChargeWithTax As Decimal
    Private _DiscountAmount As Decimal
    Private _TotalAmount As Decimal
    Private Shared LowUsageRate As Decimal
    Private Shared HighUsageRate As Decimal
    Private Shared DiscountRate As Decimal
    Private Shared TaxRate As Decimal
    Public Property Month As String
    Public Property MonthNumber As Integer
    Public Property EnergyUsage As Double
    Public ReadOnly Property MonthChargeWithTax As Decimal
        Get
            Return _MonthlyChargeWithTax
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property DiscountAmount As Decimal
        Get
            Return _DiscountAmount
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property TotalAmount As Decimal
        Get
            Return _TotalAmount
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(BillingMonth As String, MonthNum As Integer, Usage As Integer)
        Month = BillingMonth
        EnergyUsage = Usage
        MonthNumber = MonthNum
        _MonthlyChargeWithTax = CalculateGrossMonthlyBill(Usage)
        _DiscountAmount = _MonthlyChargeWithTax * DiscountRate
        _TotalAmount = _MonthlyChargeWithTax - _DiscountAmount
    End Sub

    Private Function CalculateGrossMonthlyBill(usage As Integer) As Decimal
        Dim MonthCharge As Decimal
        Select Case usage
            Case <= 200
                MonthCharge = usage * LowUsageRate
            Case Else
                MonthCharge = 200 * LowUsageRate
                MonthCharge += (usage - 200) * HighUsageRate
        End Select
        Return MonthCharge * 1.06D
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub SetRates(LowUsage As Decimal, HighUsage As Decimal, Discount As Decimal, Tax As Decimal)
        LowUsageRate = LowUsage
        HighUsageRate = HighUsage
        DiscountRate = Discount
        TaxRate = Tax
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Month
    End Function
End Class
```

The Form...

```
Public Class UtilityBills

    Private Sub UtilityBills_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        EnergyBill.SetRates(0.109D, 0.153D, 0.5D, 0.06D)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not ValidateUsage() Then
            MessageBox.Show("All text boxes must have a valid number.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim lst As New List(Of EnergyBill)
        For Each tb In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
            Dim eb As New EnergyBill(tb.Name, CInt(tb.Tag), CInt(tb.Text))
            lst.Add(eb)
        Next
        Dim orderedList = (lst.OrderBy(Function(eb) eb.MonthNumber)).ToList
        ComboBox1.DataSource = orderedList
        Dim TotalMonths = lst.Sum(Function(eb) eb.TotalAmount)
        TextBox5.Text = TotalMonths.ToString("C2")
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim eb = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, EnergyBill)
        TextBox1.Text = eb.MonthChargeWithTax.ToString("C2")
        TextBox2.Text = eb.DiscountAmount.ToString("C2")
        TextBox3.Text = eb.TotalAmount.ToString("C2")
    End Sub

    Private Function ValidateUsage() As Boolean
        Dim usage As Integer
        For Each tb In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
            If Not Integer.TryParse(tb.Text, usage) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```